Python Multiprocessing Won’t Let the Rest of the Code Execute
Ok so I’m learning how to do multiprocessing in Python after figuring out threading, the code I’ve made is a simple timer that counts up ever second until the user presses enter into the console to end the program. I made the same program with threading and it worked but when I try to do the same with multiprocessing the code never gets past the start function. Any ideas
i fixed the the problem with the Parentheses it now timer not timer()
import multiprocessing
import time

done = False


def timer():
    counter = 0
    while not done:
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer())
    p1.start()
    # This code is never reached this works when using threads
    input("Press enter to quit")
    done = True
 


Issues
The problem with your code is that you are calling the timer() function you should have passed it as the target to the multiprocessing.Process. 
You also wrote target=timer(), the timer will executed immediately, and the return value, I would imagine it would be None.
That is Not what you want— you are trying to pass the timer function itself so that it can run in a separate process.
Another thing I noticed is your variable called done which is a shared flag, You need to manage the main process as well as the child process. This scenario needs to be managed in such a way that updates are seen by the child also.
Most importantly when creating Process think of it has as a Parent to child relationship.
The parent process(any python file you have which would need to communicate with the child process (the timer function you provided) to tell it when to stop any execution.
In your case the best approach would be to use multiprocessing.Value docs
OR multiprocessing.Event docs
Here is a code snippet to guide you
import multiprocessing
import time

def timer(done):
    print("Timer started.")
    counter = 0
    while not done.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    print("Timer stopped.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    done = multiprocessing.Event()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer, args=(done,))
    p1.start()

    input("Press enter to quit\n")
    print("Stopping timer...")
    done.set()  # Signal the timer process to stop
    p1.join()   # Wait for the timer process to finish
    print("Timer process has finished.")


If you want to use it with Threading here is how it is done.
import threading
import time


def timer(done):
    print("Timer started.")
    counter = 0
    while not done.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    print("Timer stopped.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    done = threading.Event()
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=timer, args=(done,))
    p1.start()

    input("Press enter to quit\n")
    print("Stopping timer...")
    done.set()  # Signal the timer process to stop
    p1.join()  # Wait for the timer process to finish
    print("Timer process has finished.")

OR
Following the comments, your input has to be a separate thread independent of your processes. Do something like this first

import multiprocessing
import time
import threading

def timer(done):
    print("Timer has started.")
    counter = 0
    while not done.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    print("Timer would stop.")

def first_wait_for_input(done):
    input("Press enter to quit\n")
    done.set()  # signaling the timer to stop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    done = multiprocessing.Event()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timer, args=(done,))
    p1.start()

    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=first_wait_for_input, args=(done,))
    input_thread.start()

    input_thread.join()
    p1.join()
    print("Timer process has finished.")


Ok so I see the issue I caused with using timer() instead of just timer I fixed that but I still can’t get it to work even when using your code. It just goes to "Press enter to quit" then exits the program when pressed the timer never starts counting. But your code works as expected when using threads.

@user3491432 I apologise it is an oversight I have updated the code now it should work fine, I have tested it, I don't think you can mark the answer as correct as you question as being close. If you can please mark answer as correct many thanks

I tested the new code still no dice works when switched to threading but multiprocessing never gets into the while loop

you mean you ran this code and it didn't work like without any additions or extra code in it? I think what you want is how to use Threading instead of multiprocessing I have provided an alternative code for this.

so is multiprocessing just not able to do what threading does? From my understand I thought multiprocessing and threading kinda did the same thing but where different in how they accomplished it.

A process contains 1 or more threads, think of process has your browser and think of thread as opening tabs in your browser. A thread has memory , registers it etc. A process houses all the thread(s) and they all share a heap memory. If a thread dies in a process, the process is halted but a thread can survive on its own. hence the parent to child relationship. Hope that helps?

I think I found the source of the problem it has something to do with the input function. Somehow the input function freezes the process and doesn’t let it continue until input is finished. If I replace input with a sleep function the program works as expected. I find this strange.

Oh good find, but when using input, there should be a logic you should have implemented to release control back to your system or code using a keyboard  interrupt. Anyways glad you solved it.

Well I still don’t have an answer why is the input function freezing multiprocessing this doesn’t happen when using input with threading.
And I’m not sure what you mean by logic to release control back to the system, input is just a built in function of python after all.

Processes runs with diff std.err, std.in , std.out, you're making input the main thread this wouldn't work, separate the logic, you cant be using process for an input function, use a thread instead. In a multiprocessing setup, the child processes and the main process don’t share the same stdin, it would never handle synchronous properly, what you need to do is put your input function in another thread besides your process has to execute first. remember I told you your process is a browser, you can't open a tab(input) without launching browser, Let me show you an example of what you need to do.

A process will create its only std.in , but python's input comes with std.in see python docs , you can see why it will freeze https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a64aa47302bad05c4cd2e98d54e39a33722bf54f/Lib/pydoc.py#L1980

@user3491432 look at this github of what a process is from python then you would figure out the problem https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a64aa47302bad05c4cd2e98d54e39a33722bf54f/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py
